# What are the difference between col-lg and col-md in bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What are the difference between `col-lg`, `col-md` ,`col-xs` and `col-sm` grid system in in *bootstrap 3*.

In a bootstrap template they used `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>` only for one column grid.  I am a beginner in Bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference among col-lg-\*, col-md-\* and col-sm-\* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When using Bootstrap those are the classes which are added for one column grid and correspond to extra small, small, medium and large devices.

**.col-xs** = *Extra small devices (ie Phones) (<768px)

**.col-sm** = Small devices (ie Tablets) (≥768px)

**.col-md** = Medium devices (ie laptops, or small desktops) (≥992px)

**.col-lg** = Large devices (ie Desktops) (≥1200px)*

This way through media queries you can allow to have only the right classes interpreted by the browser. If you surf that website from a tablet for example, you will see that the css properties which are actually applied in the browser are only the ones for the **.col-sm** class.

**UPDATE**

Also it's important to mention that those classes are used on a grid of 12 columns in total which is the grid system setup used by Bootstrap.

Therefore when you are using `.col-sm-4` on an element it means that the element will take 4 columns out of 12 of the total width.
Which logically means that if `.col-sm-4` is used then only 3 elements per row can fit into the page on tablet.

For example, let's say we want to show some project cards for a portfolio:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 card">
    <div class="card-wrapper">  
        <img src="img.jpg">
        <div class="overlay-text">
            <h5>Project 1</h5>
            <div class="labels">
                <label>Tech Stack</label>
                <h6>HTML5, CSS, JS</h6>
            </div>       
        </div>          
    </div> 
</div>
```

Using `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"` all at the same time is used to activate different CSS properties on an element when viewing the page on a particular device.

In other terms, if the user opens the site on a desktop, `col-lg-3` means that a total of 4 cards will be displayed, when `col-md-4 means` a total of 3 cards, `col-sm-6` a total of 2 cards and then `col-xs-12` means on mobile only 1 card will with 100% width of the page.

Comment: Understood,Thanks a lot

Comment: It depends if you want to change the layout on different resolutions, if you want to have columns and not a full width layout then yes. I suggest you to give a look to: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 3):

All these tags, `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` are the part of **Bootstrap grid system**. Bootstrap's grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page. Bootstrap's grid system is responsive, and the columns will re-arrange depending on the screen size: On a big screen it might look better with the content organised in three columns, but on a small screen it would be better if the content items were stacked on top of each other.

> Tip: Remember that grid columns should add up to twelve for a row. More than that, columns will stack no matter the viewport.

**Grid System Rules**

Some Bootstrap grid system rules:

- Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows
- Predefined classes like `.row` and `.col-sm-4` are available for quickly making grid layouts
- Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on `.rows`
- Grid columns are created by specifying the number of 12 available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-sm-4`

I would recommend going through [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) and further linked pages for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

They added all those classes for one column grid in that template because those classes correspond to column extra small, small, medium and large devices.

```
.col-xs = *Extra small devices (ie Phones) (<768px)

.col-sm = Small devices (ie Tablets) (≥768px)

.col-md = Medium devices (ie laptops, or small desktops) (≥992px)

.col-lg = Large devices (ie Desktops) (≥1200px)*
```