# Bootstrap column width issue within an iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

*** Edit ***

Accidentally wrong picture was uploaded for standalone case. Now corrected

*** Edit ***

I am unable to set the column widths (with col-) within and iframe. The CSS selector seems to be completely ignored. The very same page if requested as a standalone page (not iframe) works as expected. Please see the attached pictures.

Standalone:

[image]
Within iframe:

[image: Within iframe]

Comment: They both look the same to me... both showing 600x34 with padding 0 15px.  No difference in size, according to your screen shots.

Comment: You are right. Accidentally wrong pics were uploaded. I've already edited and corrected.

Comment: Looks like the iframe is rendering smaller.  So you using col-lg-2 may be ignored if the iframe has a media size for sm or xs.  Try changing that line to `<div class="col-sm-2">` and see if it renders correctly in your iframe.

Comment: @Jacob Roberts: Bingo! Using col-sm solves this. I am still not understand why col-lg it is not working, the iframe was 1000px with but anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out of the box media widths are

> -xs smaller than 768px
>
> -sm 768px
>
> -md 992px
>
> -lg 1200px

So with your iframe set to 1000 will fall in the -md category.  The way the columns work is, it will default to 12 wide if it is smaller than what is listed.  Since you had it set to -lg and the iframe was only 1000, then the width automatically adjusted to 12 wide.

Example col-xs-6 will be 6 regardless of how big or small you make the screen but if you use col-sm-6, then it will be 6 until the screen width goes below 768px, which then it will automatically jump to 12 columns wide.

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242455/what-are-the-difference-between-col-lg-and-col-md-in-bootstrap3/20242655#20242655