# Bootstrap divs in smaller media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have 4 divs displaying in a row.
When the window is made smaller it turns into 2 rows with 2 divs on each row.
I am trying to add an in between layer where it collapses into 3 divs on the top (with the extra one below)

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <p>2</p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add a 3rd class between col-xs-6 and col-sm-3 but haven't been able to get it working. 
I am not quite sure of the terminology around what I am trying to do - which I think might be why I am having trouble searching for an answer

Thanks

Comment: So you want the 3rd div on top and the 4th div in second row, on smaller screens? [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/8d8ukky9/)

Comment: @TheUknown Here is what I want to happen as you make the browser smaller: http://postimg.org/image/f02mgwg4t/
Currently step 1 is going straight to step 3. But I want to add step 2 (But still keep step 1 and 3)

Comment: Ok I just tried         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 "> which has worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by updating each div to apply the following classes:

```
col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242455/what-are-the-difference-between-col-lg-and-col-md-in-bootstrap3/20242655#20242655

Answer (score 0):

Try This

https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/erf2zcrp/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 color">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 color">
          <p>2</p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 color">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 color">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 hidden-sm color">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap works with 4 pre-defined break points in widths ( xs, sm, md, lg )
From what I understand, You want to create a new media-query between that sizes (<768px and <992px)

To do so you`ll have to create it and add a new class at your divs

For example..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 800px) { 
  .row > .col-ss-4 {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
```

}

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5s43u65/)