# Bootstrap col-xs and col-sm

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my bootstrap col-xs working from 768px is that normal , i know the xs is working fro 480px ?

```
 <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <p><img src="img/wdigets/1.jpg" class="img-circle" width="66" height="66"></p>
    <p class="name">Johnny Carr</p>
    <p class="big-number">21</p>
</li>
```

[MY DEMO](http://mohammadsamy.com/stackover/widgets.html)

please check the Inbox Summery box the li make 100% when the size become 768px !!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242455/what-are-the-difference-between-col-lg-and-col-md-in-bootstrap3

Comment: what do  you expect? 12 is the full width. Which is 100%

Comment: xs working from 480px  not 768px right !!

Comment: What do you mean not right? What is right for you?

Comment: i need to target 480px

Comment: So you need customize the css. [Take a look at docs, there is no 480px support](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you're wrong. Bootstrap 3 col-xs is working from <768px. The grid of bootstrap 3 is:

```
.col-xs = (<768px)

.col-sm = (≥768px)

.col-md = (≥992px)

.col-lg = (≥1200px)
```

But.. With bootstrap 4, alpha, they have added a new format to the list, a extra large column. The grid of bootstrap 4 is:

```
.col-xs = (<544px)

.col-sm = (≥544px)

.col-md = (≥768px)

.col-lg = (≥992px)

.col-xl = (≥1200px)
```

Hope this hepls you out

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.

.col-xs = *Extra small devices (ie Phones) (<768px)

.col-sm = Small devices (ie Tablets) (≥768px)

.col-md = Medium devices (ie laptops, or small desktops) (≥992px)

.col-lg = Large devices (ie Desktops) (≥1200px)*

Source link: [What are the difference between col-lg and col-md in bootstrap3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242455/what-are-the-difference-between-col-lg-and-col-md-in-bootstrap3)