# Bootstrap 3 dealing with difference between xs and sm

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using col-xs-* for mobile devices in portrait, but naively believed col-sm-* was for landscape mobile devices, however, according to the first answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371088/bootstrap-col-xs-and-col-sm), it is in fact not.

So my question is how do I effectively use the col structure for landscape phones?

My idea was:

- col-xs-12 on vertical mobile
- col-sm-6 on landscape mobile (as it is evidently wider)

However, because sm is not what I originally thought it to be, is this possible without changing the core bootstrap CSS?

If we look at an iPhone 6+ for example, in it's landscape orientation it's width is 736px, which is still considered within the bounds of xs.

So then anything col-xs-12 in this viewport looks absolutely huge, which makes things look terrible.

Theoretically I could change the sm break-point to lower than the current value of 768, however is there a better way of doing this?

Maybe adding a class between xs and sm?

**UPDATE**

I also found this snippet from another question, which has potential.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xsl-6{ width: 50%; }
}
```

Comment: did you think about migrating to BS-4?

Comment: I had thought about it but I have not yet had a chance to jump into the Alpha release of Bootstrap 4. Given this I am not too aware of every change.

I would migrate if it were my own project but unfortunately it's towards the end and I don't think the other developers would appreciate the potential testing involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, taking into account others advice I decided it would be beneficial to make an xsl col class as suggested.

Below is the CSS.

```
/* Specifally landscape phones */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

.col-xsl-1, .col-xsl-2, .col-xsl-3, .col-xsl-4, .col-xsl-5, .col-xsl-6, .col-xsl-7, .col-xsl-8, .col-xsl-9, .col-xsl-10, .col-xsl-11, .col-xsl-12 {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .col-xsl-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xsl-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xsl-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xsl-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xsl-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xsl-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Admittedly it is probably easier to just wait for Bootstrap 4 or use LESS CSS but if you're look for a simplistic, CSS only solution then this should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use LESS and change the `sm` breakpoint:

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
@screen-sm-min: 736px;
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/g3Qtejhoui

You can also [generate a custom CSS build](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) changing the same `@screen-sm-min` variable.

Comment: I feel like this is the most reasonable approach given my situation, however I'm still stuck using CSS, so will change it where appropriate... I really do need to get into pre-processed CSS.