# what is the difference between col-lg-4 and col-md-3 and col-xs-3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For the field size i gave col-lg-4 and col-Md-3 and col-XS-2.but at last the column size is 4 only then why we need col-MD-3 and col-XS-2.explain me please...

texttext 1

Comment: you need to read the `bootstrap` documentation for that. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference among col-lg-\*, col-md-\* and col-sm-\* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 7):

You can see [the Bootstrap grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) for the details, should they be updated at some date after this reply.

---

The syntax of a Bootstrap column class name is constructed as follows:

```
. {prefix} - {when to collapse} - {number of grid columns to occupy}
```

The  `prefix`  in the above is  `col` , indicating that the element is a part of the Bootstrap column system.

The `when to collapse`  option ( `xs`,  `sm`,  `md` or  `lg`) indicate at what width the columns should stop being displayed inline and collapse to be positioned above each other instead.

The  `number of grid columns to occupy`  indicates how large portion of the whole row the classable element should occupy. A whole row is made up of a total of **12** columns in Bootstrap.

The collapsing widths are currently defined as follows:

- `xs` - the grid is horizontal at all times, the container is styled as `width: auto`, meaning it will take up all the space currently available.
- `sm` - the grid is horizontal past a breaking point of 750px of width.
- `md` - *ibid* (as previously), but from 970px.
- `lg` - *ibid*, but from 1170px.

Shortly put, the different collapsing options allow you to define at what width your layout should collapse: as a simplified explanation, at what window width the mobile view of the page (or similar)
should be shown.

The documentation linked at the beginning of this reply also offers a number of examples.

Comment: thank u...For example if i want my page have to view in desktop,tablet,mobile..so for this i have to give collapse option lg,md,sm..right...explain me please...

Comment: You can only specify one of the collapsing options. The defined class specifies at what width the layout should reflow.