# Bootstrap confusion between size number and size name in col-xx-6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, to give divs a width we are using col-xx-6 for example, here it will span 6 columns, so what's the use of xx? what is the difference between using sm and md? I tried it and couldn't see the difference. seems like the 6 is only affecting that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference among col-lg-\*, col-md-\* and col-sm-\* in twitter bootstrap3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-twitter-bootstra)

Comment: `XX` are for screen sizes.