# Wordpress theme development and bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I just started to explore the Bootstrap project which seems nice to use in web development. I read some articles, some of them where sceptical to the combination of Wordpress and Bootstrap. This was due to the fact that (as I understand it) Bootstrap has it's own pre defined classes that you are supposed to add to your html tags,  while Wordpress has another set of classes for the same elements.

I understand the problem and I would like to know if there are any "best practices" regarding this. I know that there exists plugins for this task but I like to understand this myself. I think that the trickiest part is the auto generated wp-menus and those things, am I right?

**Question:**
I think (without further investigation) that I in some situations want to map a wordpress class (eg. wp-menu classes) to a Bootstrap class. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap will help you to build responsive theme for wordpress quickly. You can check the following link to know the [difference of major common twitter bootstrap's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-twitter-bootstra) classes that means when you should use which sets of class. If you want to add or alter the class of Wordpress menu, you should customize the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class. This [link](http://www.creativewebdesign.ro/en/blog/wordpress/create-a-responsive-wordpress-theme-with-bootstrap-3-header-and-footer/) will help you. You can follow the [wordpress standard](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). And finally there are many wordpress theme development frameworks which have already bootstrap. i.e. [roots](https://roots.io/), [underscores](http://underscores.me/) and so on. I like these both.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it is much clearer now!