# How do I evenly distribute data into 4 columns in php?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a project in PHP that pulls pictures from a Facebook page using Facebook SDK. I am using a loop to echo 40 different images, I want to distribute these images evenly between 4 different bootstrap columns as shown below.

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
Image1      Image2      Image3      Image4
Image5      Image6      Image7      Image8
```

The loop I am currently using to echo images into one column:

```
  foreach($rData as $post) {
   $image = ('<center><img class="img-responsive" src="'.$post->getProperty('full_picture').'"/>'.'</br></center>');
   print('<div class="col-sm-12">'.$image.'</div'); 
  }
```

I've spent quite some time trying to figure this out but can never seem to distribute the data without having it repeat. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `array_chunk` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using array_chunk:

```
foreach(array_chunk($rData, 4) as $chunk)
{
    print('<div class="row">');
    foreach($chunk as $post) {
       $image = ('<center><img class="img-responsive" src="'.$post->getProperty('full_picture').'"/>'.'</br></center>');
       print('<div class="col-sm-3">'.$image.'</div>'); 
    }
    print('</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
print('<div class="col-sm-12">'.$image.'</div');
```

To:

```
print('<div class="col-sm-3">'.$image.'</div');
```

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid.  If you tell each element to only take up 3 of those columns, then you will get 4 across on a larger screen.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865627/697370) to help you determine how far down in screen size you want to keep those 4 columns before you reach a break point.

Answer (score 0):

You can check when is the last element (4) in your line, and put something (html element) to broken to the next line:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($rData as $post) {
    $myDivisor = '' //nothing yet

    if( ($i%4) == 0 )
        $myDivisor = 'something...';

    $image = ('<center><img class="img-responsive" src="'.$post->getProperty('full_picture').'"/>'.'</br></center>');

    print('<div class="col-sm-12">'.$image.'</div>'.$myDivisor);

    $i++;

...
```