# Columns are not responsive in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to make the columns stack under each other when on mobile screen, but have them show side by side on desktop. I'm confused as hell, this should be super simple but I can't see my bug...

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <img class="ratio" src="img/about1.jpg">
                <div class="about-heading">Our Services</div>
                <div>Replace this content with your own content. Content should be relevant, unique and written with the goal of providing the reader the type of information they are looking for while motivating them to take action.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <img class="ratio" src="img/about2.jpg">
                <div class="about-heading">About Us</div>
                <div>Replace this content with your own content. Content should be relevant, unique and written with the goal of providing the reader the type of information they are looking for while motivating them to take action.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

http://goo.gl/woSq0c

Comment: you might have overridden the default bootstrap behaviors in your ccs file!

Comment: assuming I had overridden default behaviours, which file would I need to update, the style.css file or the bootstrap.css file

Comment: the style.css, you have noting to do with bootstrap.css because if you edit it it may cause some unwanted behaviors

Comment: I would start by removing col-sm-12 col-xs-12 from your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one of `col-md-` `col-sm-` `col-xs-`.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865627/2181514.

Bootstrap has 12 columns, but both your columns are set to fill all 12, so they will never be next to each other.   Use `-6` only.

Change both

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

to just

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
```