# What is the difference between the **col-md-4** class and the **col-xs-4** class in BootStrap template?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new in Twitter BootStrap and I have the following doubt.

I have clear how the BootStrap grid layout works so if I have something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
</div>
```

simply means that I have a row divided into 3 columns of the 4 dimension (because the BootStrap grid layout is based on 12 columns)

My doubt is related to the **md** definition of these columns.

I know that I can use also something like `<div class="col-xs-4">`

What exatly is the difference between the **col-md-4** class and the **col-xs-4** class?

Comment: It's all explained in the docs. It relates to how it's supposed to behave on screens of different sizes.

Comment: Just read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: See the Docs > [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference among col-lg-\*, col-md-\* and col-sm-\* in twitter bootstrap3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-twitter-bootstra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically,

it will define the behavior of the columns in **xl** (extra large screens) and in **md** (medium screens);

Ex: when the screen is **xl** the columns will have the proportion where 12 is the sum of the columns, if the screen get smaller the columns will break. however, if you setup with **md** you can get the screen even smaller but the columns will no break until the dimensions:

- xs (for phones)
- sm (for tablets)
- md (for desktops)
- lg (for larger desktops)

reference: 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/