# Do I need to specify col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 to get 100% width in all devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In order to get 100% width, do I need to specify `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">**</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-twitter-bootstra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just need col-xs-12. The column allocation for the smallest screen applies to all larger devices unless a new column allocation is made.