# Bootstrap columns conventions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to Google the question but couldn't find any related topic. What is better approach to using Bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
```

Is it good or bad idea to omit column classes even if they are redundant?

Comment: it's a good idea, because in this way you don't use more classes than you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this has [already been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap/19865627).

The smaller grid classes *also* apply to larger screens unless overriden specifically by a larger breakpoint. For example, `col-md-6` alone means 6 units on **medium and up**.

Therefore, you only need to use the class for the *smallest* device width you want to support.

Also, the `col-xs-12` is implied since, columns will stack vertically (and become full-width) on xs screens unless you use a specific `col-xs-{1-11}` class in your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, `col-lg-6` and `col-sm-12` are meaningless here as those will inherit the styles from `col-md-6` and `col-xs-12`.

There's no harm in keeping the `col-lg-6` and `col-sm-12` - they offer some security in that it guarantees a large display will render `col-lg-6` (in the event your `col-md-6` is dynamically modified), but you'd be better off not including them in your HTML purely to make your HTML file size smaller.