# Setting (bootstrap) col width's with media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive

I have a page with a banner and 3 columns, and I am trying to make it so that when the screen width gets too small, that the first 2 columns change from 1/3rd width to 50% width and the last column width change to 100% so that it's below the first two.

When I do this, the height of the columns does change (they change to 50%, considering the columns will now fit underneath each other inside a 100% row), but the width does not. How could I fix this? Thanks in advance!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/NYrjRP)

HTML

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="aboutBanner"> </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

      </div>
      <div class="col">

      </div>
      <div class="col">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

related CSS

```
.aboutBanner {
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row {
    height: 70%;
}

.row .col {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .row .col:nth-of-type(1),
    .row .col:nth-of-type(2) {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .row .col:nth-of-type(3) {
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        border-style: dashed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Bootstrap responsive grid columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMzRyb

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="aboutBanner">

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-6">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-6">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

To visualize this in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMzRyb) I changed the CSS...

```
.row {
    height: 70%;
}

.row > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Also see:
[What is the difference among col-lg-*, col-md-* and col-sm-* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap)

Comment: please accept an answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 1):

## Use bootstrap col-[size] class

[See documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

The bootstrap grid is based in 12 columns sizes, that are divided in 5 screen sizes:

- Extra small

  - `col-[1 to 12]`
- Small

  - `col-sm-[1 to 12]`
- Medium

  - `col-md-[1 to 12]`
- Large

  - `col-lg-[1 to 12]`
- Extra large

  - `col-xl-[1 to 12]`

Try this:

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="aboutBanner"> </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          content of first
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          content of second
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          content of third
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*Keep in mind that 12 is 100%, 6 is 50%, 4 is 33%, 3 is 25% and so on...*

Comment: `col` is a valid Bootstrap class. Having 3 col's basically means they are all equal width. I just found it strange that I couldn't overwrite the width with a media query. The reason I want to use a media query for this is so I can set my own width instead of relying on Bootstrap's predefined width.