# Is there a bootstrap class to handle all col widths?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been building dynamic HTML to handle desktop/mobile width dimensions with the bootstrap grid system.

Is there a way to combine css classes in a "parent" class to limit duplicate code?

Example,
Change:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="all-column"></div>
```

Where the .all-column class combines all class widths into one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you can't inherit from another class in CSS, but you can in CSS pre-processors like SASS.

However, using the same col for each breakpoint is unneccessary:

`<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>`

Because, this is the *same* thing:

`<div class="col-xs-6"></div>`

Read [how the Bootstrap grid classes work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap/19865627#19865627).

Comment: Really?  Interesting.  Could you clarify how the ".col-xs-6" class handles all other width sizes?  It was my understanding that that class only handles widths less than 768px.

Comment: Please read the [answer I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap/19865627#19865627) or refer to the Bootstrap docs.

Comment: @BigBen_Davy — RTFM: [Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome links. Will definitely work on RTFM! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
```

This will take care of other classes automatically col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Can you expand on how the ".col-xs-6" class handles all other width sizes? It was my understanding it was only for displays that had a width less than 768px.