# Bootstrap 4 grid - .col-breakpoint vs .col-number

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm migrating from Bootstrap 3 to 4 and trying to understand the differences when it comes to the grid.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

It says:

> - Thanks to flexbox, grid columns without a specified width will automatically layout as equal width columns. For example, four instances of `.col-sm` will each automatically be 25% wide from the small breakpoint and up.
> - Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use `.col-4`.

Given this, what would be the difference between using:

1. Four instances of `.col-sm`
2. Four instances of `.col-3`

Both of these would occupy 25% width of a `.row`. Correct?

So what's the difference between specifying it either way?

In Bootstrap 3 you *had to* use the specific numbers within a 12 column grid, e.g. using 4 instances of `.col-sm-3` meant you would have 4 (25% width) columns since 12/3 = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **"Given this, what would be the difference between using:"**
>
> - Four instances of `.col-sm`
> - Four instances of `.col-3`

Yes, in some cases they'd appear the same, but `col-3` would never stack vertically since is applies to the smallest (xs) breakpoint. However, the `col-md` will stack vertically on the medium breakpoint of less than 768px.

https://www.codeply.com/go/xi74w61tdk

Outside of your use case using 4 columns, `col-3` will always be 25% width. `col-md` will grow equally regardless of the number columns.

---

Also see: [What is the difference among col-lg-*, col-md-* and col-sm-* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 3** grid system we had 4 breakpoints

Extra small (for smartphones .col-xs-*)

Small (for tablets .col-sm-*)

Medium (for laptops .col-md-*)

Large (for laptops/desktops .col-lg-*).

---

In **Bootstrap 4** there is a new -xl- size. Also the -xs- infix has been removed, so smallest columns are simply col-1, col-2.. col-12, etc..

col-* - 0 (xs)

col-sm-* - 576px

col-md-* - 768px

col-lg-* - 992px

col-xl-* - 1200px