# Ordering divs using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If I have 2 divs and I want to show them in different orders depending on the screen size breakpoint do I have to specify the order for each size? eg

```
<div class="order-xs-2 order-sm-2 order-md-2 order-lg-1 order-xl-1">
<div class="order-xs-1 order-sm-1 order-md-1 order-lg-2 order-xl-2">
```

When I tried this they appeared correctly in all sizes apart from xs, where they were the wrong way round so I suspect I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: I think bootstrap 4 `xs` class is removed - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set the *smallest* breakpoints, the larger breakpoints are implied. Also, remember that the ordering classes use **flexbox** so they'll only work in a `display:flex` parent such as `.row` or `.d-flex`...

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="order-2 order-lg-1">div 1</div>
    <div class="order-1 order-lg-2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/YZVC3UPvoG

`-xs` is no longer used in Bootstrap 4. The smallest breakpoint is the default, so it's just `order-1`, `order-2` etc..

---

Also see: [What is the difference among col-lg-*, col-md-* and col-sm-* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the sizes that worked, there is no `order-xs`.

Answer (score -1):

Current available sizes are `sm` `md` `lg` `xl` if you want to set the order below `sm` size don't use size before order and override it with the size that you want

### example

```
<div class="order-sm-2 order-1">
<div class="order-sm-1 order-2">
```