# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid, responsive

Newly trying to do stuff with Bootstrap for a responsive banner. I did some researching last night and this morning. If this has already been answered (like I suspect), please let me know where I might be able to find the answer. I set up a 4 column, 1 row grid. I put some content in each column. However, when I reduce the size of the browser window enough, it turns into something that looks like it has 4 rows instead of one. Please check the linked video capture of my browser (chrome) being resized. The code I'm using is at the pastebin below. How do i keep it all in one row, all of the time?

Partial Code:

```
<div class="container touchpointContainer">
 <div class="row tall">
   <div class="col-sm-1 bootCol">
     <a onclick="advanceReview(-1)">
       <img class="prev" src="leftArrow.png"/>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 bootCol">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore"
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 bootCol">
     Image goes here
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1 bootCol">
     <a onclick="advanceReview(1)">
       <img class="next" src="rightArrow.png"/>
     </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Complete Code:

https://pastebin.com/N2dYk5J5

Gif of resizing:

https://media1.giphy.com/media/VgfuWp1UiKPTqznZvc/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional searching after posting this question. It seems like the answer is stored here:

[What is the difference among col-lg-*, col-md-* and col-sm-* in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-bootstrap/19865627)

There's a good gif there that shows exactly what the behavior is like.

And the answer is... To fix it use col-1 instead of col-sm-1. Just remove the 'sm' from the class names for all the columns.